# How to get random data in SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, sqlite

I am trying to get a random order by using `Order by NEWID()` as the following:

```
public Cursor getSpecialList(String bloodCategory) {        
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + colName + " ," +
        "" + colFather + " ," +
        "" + colFamily + " ,"+
        "" + colPhone + " from " + ListInfoTable +
        " WHERE " + colBloodCategory + "='" + bloodCategory + "'" +
        " order by NEWID() ", new String[]{});    
    return cur;     
}
```

**SQLite** Log gives me the following error:

> No such function NEWID

Comment: Is column name is `NEWID()` in `ListInfoTable` table?

Comment: Just provide `Column Name`. Which you want to `Order By`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Is that possible to give a `Table Column Name` like `NEWID()`?

Comment: NEWID function available on sql to get a random order Regardless the name of columns it is built in function

Comment: guys try it on sql  , it is work and give a random order

Comment: @MohamadMahmoud: In sqlite need to use `RANDOM()` instead of `NEWID`

Comment: @MD: Yes possible to use `()` in column name but not good practice to use any special character in column name

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Ya that's what i am talkin about....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code for random data:

```
public Cursor getSpecialList(String bloodCategory )
        {       

      SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+colName+" ,"+
            ""+colFather+" ,"+
            ""+colFamily+" ,"+
            ""+colPhone+" from "+ListInfoTable+
            " WHERE "+colBloodCategory+"='"+bloodCategory+"'"+
            " ORDER BY RANDOM() ",new String[] {});    
      return cur;       
    }
```

Comment: I update the question, could you please vote up .thanks